# Finding a conformal mapping from one space to another

Tags: complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

I am having trouble understanding how to go about finding a conformal mapping from one arbitrary space to another. I have made a few assumptions, but I am not sure if these are all correct. I assume the first step is to use FLT operations to try to get closer to our goal, but I do not fully understand what FLT inversions and multiplications look like for different spaces. I assume we change the complex numbers to polar form to get a better idea of what the complex number does, but this doesn't help me much in practice problems. I know that FLTs map circles and lines to circles and lines, but I don't know to target these areas using FLTS.
Is there any vague rule of thumb about what direction to go in when faced with any of these problems? I know that I am missing fundamental understanding of the workings of FLT operations, but I can't seem to understand it. If anyone has a good explanation for these, it would help a lot!

Comment: For domains that can be transformed into one another by fractional linear transformations, you can work by combining translations $z\mapsto z+a$, rotations $z\mapsto e^{it}z$, [homotheties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) $z\mapsto rz$ with $r$ real, and inversions $z\mapsto 1/z$ (actually an [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) followed by a reflection with respect to the $X$-axis but some people call this inversion too).

Comment: I suppose you are familiar with what translations, rotations and homotheties (even if you call this one contraction/expansion) do. For inversions you can take a look at what they do geometrically to a figure in the link above.